# Unclear problem with nullreferenceexception, C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There is a section of XAML code:

```
<TextBox Name="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="480,271,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" FontSize="15" Text="Своя идеология1" TextChanged="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1_TextChanged"/>
<TextBox Name="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="480,310,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" FontSize="15" Text="Своя идеология2" TextChanged="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox2_TextChanged"/>
<TextBox Name="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="480,349,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" FontSize="15" Text="Своя идеология3" TextChanged="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox3_TextChanged"/>
<TextBox Name="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="480,387,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" FontSize="15" Text="Своя идеология4" TextChanged="CustomIdeologyNameTextBox4_TextChanged"/>
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="480,432,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <TextBlock>democracy</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>communism</TextBlock>
            <TextBlockfascism></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>neutrality</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="ComboBoxCustomIdeology1" Text="Своя идеология 1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="ComboBoxCustomIdeology2" Text="Своя идеология 2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="ComboBoxCustomIdeology3" Text="Своя идеология 3"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="ComboBoxCustomIdeology4" Text="Своя идеология 4"></TextBlock>
        </ComboBox>
```

And here is the code for it:

```
private void CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology1.Text = CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1.Text;
            }
            catch(NullReferenceException)
            {
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology1.Text = "-";
            }
        }

        private void CustomIdeologyNameTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology2.Text = CustomIdeologyNameTextBox2.Text;
            }
            catch
            {
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology2.Text = "-";
            }

        }

        private void CustomIdeologyNameTextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology3.Text = CustomIdeologyNameTextBox3.Text;
            }
            catch
            {
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology3.Text = "-";

            }
        }

        private void CustomIdeologyNameTextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try { 
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology4.Text = CustomIdeologyNameTextBox4.Text;
            }
            catch
            {
                ComboBoxCustomIdeology3.Text = "-";
            }
        }
```

That is, the last four options in the combobox must have the text of the four textboxes.
But for some reason, when compiling, it throws a NullReferenceException. Processing blocks do not help - everything is the same. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Which line throws the NRE?

Comment: are you getting exception when compiling?

Comment: `<TextBlockfascism></TextBlock>` should probably be `<TextBlock>fascism</TextBlock>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1` with `Text="Своя идеология1"` before `ComboBoxCustomIdeology1` is initiliazed. When `CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1_TextChanged` is called, `ComboBoxCustomIdeology1` is not initialized and is null.

Probably the fastest solution will be check if `ComboBoxCustomIdeologyX` is not null

```
private void CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBoxCustomIdeology1 != null)
    {
        ComboBoxCustomIdeology1.Text = CustomIdeologyNameTextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Similar for other ComboBoxCustomIdeology